# Ignore dead mirrror on stretch lite

Tags: raspbian-stretch, raspbian-lite

apperantly, my upgrade on jesse lite or stretch lite, both get to download something from ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de, which apparently is really dead or at least it not going to 100%!

```
    83% [Connecting to ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de (137.226.34.46)]
Err:2 http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf ncurses-bin armhf 6.0+20161126-1+deb9u1
  Could not connect to ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de:80 (137.226.34.46), connection timed out [IP: 137.226.34.46 80]
Err:10 http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf perl-modules-5.24 all 5.24.1-3+deb9u2
  Unable to connect to ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de:http: [IP: 137.226.34.46 80]
....
```

after 83% is going dead.

How can I ignore this mirror on my source.list so it takes the packages from another mirror.

my current source.list:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

Comment: Can you add output from the command `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`?